# Complex Limit containing gamma and digamma function:

Tags: limits, asymptotics, exponential-function, gamma-function, digamma-function

Consider the following function :

$$f(x)=\frac{x\Gamma'(x)}{(\Gamma(x))^2}-\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}$$

I need to calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}\frac {|f(x+iy)|}{e^{2πy}}$$

I 'guessed' with some approximate analysis that this limit is zero but I couldn't be sure of that.

For that guess I used the estimate :

$$|\Gamma\left(x+iy\right)|\sim\sqrt{2\pi}|y|^{x-(1/2)}e^{-\pi|y|/2}    (1+O(\frac{1}{|y|}))$$

As $|y|\rightarrow\infty$

$C$ and $c$ are constants

And so, $$\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}\frac {f(x+iy)}{e^{2πy}}= 0$$

Comment: Does [this](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11) help you?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson thank you for the comment but I know this already.

Comment: You'd be surprised how many times I have sent people links to DLMF or the wolfram functions site and people don't even know they exist. You clearly have done your homework though.  Sorry it didn't help.